# Finder tags not saved for downloaded files

Tags: finder-tag

When I save a file and add tags to it in the save dialog box, these tags are not added to the file. This happens in all browsers I have tried (Safari, Firefox, Chrome). Tags do appear to get added to files when they are created locally in an application. This just seems to be an issue when downloading a file. This seems to happen with any file that is downloaded to any folder on my Mac.

I have searched everywhere and only found [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8102323) on discussions.apple.com from 2017. It is focused only on a similar issue with Microsoft Office that Apple claimed was not their fault, and that was fixed when upgrading to a newer version of Office.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated, this issue has disrupted a lot of automation I have set up for sorting files.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on a Early 2014 MacBook Air, 1.4GHz i5, 4GB RAM and 120GB SSD.

**Edit #2:** I just tested this again after clearing my Finder cache and restarting Finder. Firefox and Safari still delete tags assigned on download, but Chrome works. Any idea why this might be the case and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: I've not used tags since OS9 due to the way Apple implemented the colors, but I can confirm the behavior. Safari saves files with tags but if you try the same with Firefox: no tags. Annoying, I'm sure. That *might just* be a Firefox bug rather than something we can help you with though... You can submit Firefox bugs here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/home

Comment: It's not in Firefox only. It happens with any browser I use (Firefox, Safari, Chrome), as I said in my post.

Comment: Update: I just tested this again after clearing my Finder cache and restarting Finder. Firefox and Safari still delete tags assigned on download, but Chrome works. Any idea why this might be the case?